# SQL Query to get the artists with more than 3 albums and the name of those artists

Tags: sql

I need a query that will get the artists with more than one album and also show the name of those artists along with the total number of albums they have. This consists of two tables ALBUM and ARTIST both of which have an ARTISTID but only the ARTIST table has the artist's name.

I have the following but im not sure what to do from here:

`SELECT ARTISTID FROM ALBUMS GROUP BY ARTISTID HAVING COUNT(ARTISTID) >= 3`

This gives me the ARTISTID from the ALBUM tables that occurs at least 3 times.

ALBUM TABLE:
[ALBUM TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0TMY.png)

ARTIST TABLE:[ARTIST TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpw8A.png)

Comment: Make sure to filter out Nickelback.

Comment: @Max Funniest comment I've heard in a while.  We could also jest about the Avril Lavigne short lived marriage, but I won't go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` and `group by` as follows:

```
SELECT AR.ARTISTID, AR.ARTISTNAME, COUNT(*) NUM_OF_ALBUM
FROM ALBUMS A JOIN ARTIST AR ON A.ARTISTID = AR.ARTISTID
GROUP BY AR.ARTISTID, AR.ARTISTNAME 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```